# Idiomatic way to parse binary data into primitive types

Tags: rust

I've written the following method to parse binary data from a gzipped file using [GzDecoder from the Flate2 library](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs)

```
fn read_primitive<T: Copy>(reader: &mut GzDecoder<File>) -> std::io::Result<T>
{
    let sz = mem::size_of::<T>();
    let mut vec =  Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(sz);
    let ret: T;
    unsafe{
        vec.set_len(sz);
        let mut s = &mut vec[..];
        try!(reader.read(&mut s));

        let ptr :*const u8 = s.as_ptr();
        ret = *(ptr as *const T)
    }
    Ok(ret)
}
```

It works, but I'm not particularly happy with the code, especially with using the dummy vector and the temporary variable `ptr`. It all feels very inelegant to me and I'm sure there's a better way to do this. I'd be happy to hear any suggestions of how to clean up this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse binary protocols with Rust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693824/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-binary-protocols-with-rust)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code allows *any* copyable `T`, not just primitives. That means you could try to parse in something with a reference, which is probably not what you want:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Foo(&str);
```

However, the general sketch of your code is what I'd expect. You need a temporary place to store some data, and then you must convert that data to the appropriate primitive (perhaps dealing with endinaness issues).

I'd recommend the [byteorder](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/byteorder/) library. With it, you call specific methods for the primitive that is required:

```
reader.read_u16::<LittleEndian>()
```

Since these methods know the desired size, they can stack-allocate an array to use as the temporary buffer, which is likely a bit more efficient than a heap-allocation. Additionally, I'd suggest changing your code to accept a generic object with the `Read` trait, instead of the specific `GzDecoder`.

You may also want to look into a serialization library like [rustc-serialize](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize) or [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) to see if they fit any of your use cases.